# html : input is not clickable after changing position

Tags: html, css

I have a list of inputs and I changed their size and their position , but after the changes some inputs become not clickable (the name input and the username input). I'm using bootstrap. They work in stackoverflow snippet but they don't work when you run the code on the browser or on any online html runner.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1 style="position: relative;right: 470px;">create account </h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4">name</label>
    <input style="width: 400px" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="position: relative;right: 60px;">
    <label for="inputPassword4">username</label>
    <input style="width: 400px" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="position: relative;right: 70px;">
    <label for="inputAddress">email</label>
    <input style="width: 915px" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
  </div>


  <label for="inputEmail4" style="position: relative;right: 70px;">              password
          </label>
  <input style="position: relative;right: 70px;width: 915px" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">

  <br>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="outline:none;position: relative;right: 70px;margin-bottom: 20px;">submit </button>
```

Comment: We can't help you fix the problem if we can't see the code that's causing it! You even said that you know it works here, so we can't fix code that isn't broken :) This code works so it is it is being caused by something else that you have not shown us. You will need to do some more debugging to narrow it down and then edit your question to include a minimal,reproducible example that also has the relevant HTML, so we can see what might be going wrong and be able to help.

Comment: I don't know why it works here but try running it locally and you'll see what I'm talking about. For the code it is in the question I don't get why you say ' if we can't see the code that's causing it'

Comment: Maybe try using the correct Bootstrap classes and don't try to change the Bootstrap styling with inline CSS? Mixing responsive grids and fixed widths isn't going to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `for` attribute value for label and `id` attribute value for input the same value for each label-input pair

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label